# How to get extract Xpath for following?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

How to get exract xpath for the following name(I1888 - Child 1.1). now i am using following xpath "//span[contains(@class,'TreeTitleRed')][contains(.,'Child 1.1')]" but i need to get xpath without contains. please help me

```html
    <div>
      <span> class ="Vegan tree"
       <span class="treeTitlered">I1888 -Child 1.1</span>
     </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following if you want it in xpath

```
//span[@class='treeTitlered']
```

Or you can directly find the locator by using the classname

```
driver.findElement(By.className(“treeTitlered”));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use.

```
//div/child::span[1]/child::span[1]
```

This will surely work for you, do let me know in case of any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
//div/span/child::span[@class="treeTitlered"]

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to parent [`<span>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and locate it using its [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) of `Vegan tree`.

Once done you can query its [innerText property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) which will return `I1888 - Child 1.1` text

Example code (assumes [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) just in case)

```
WebElement veganTree = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By
                        .xpath("//span[@class='Vegan tree']")));

System.out.println(veganTree.getAttribute("innerText"));
```

Demo:

[image]